MSC, MSB, MPC and MPB in privately funded news organization?
I have thought of 2 possible ways the MSC (Marginal Social Cost), MPC (Marginal Private Cost), MSB (Marginal Social Benefit) and MPB (Marginal Private Benefit) could differ for a privately funded news organization vs a independent publicly funded news organization with very little bias (think the BBC for an example).

Private news organizations are incentivized to overreport on news that may increase viewership and profits and underreport on news that would not garner as much attention. They would likely report/cover news from a selective perspective in order to appeal to their existing viewer base.

Private news organizations might obtain some funding from wealthy donors, lobbying groups, etc, which could similarly lead to selective coverage of the news.


Could someone explain how the MSC, MSB, MPC and MPB in these situations would differ from those of an idealized publicly funded news organization with little bias? Thank you!

Please type out the abbreviations at least once, e.g. the first time they occur in the body of the question.

Apologies, I have done so @Giskard
